# Propagating C# Mouse Leave Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a c# Desktop Application and I've made a usercontrol which have a button and i want to make this button only visible when i am inside this user control but there is a problem:

When i hover over the button inside the mouse control, that is detected as a MouseLeave for the usercontrol which makes a big problem.

Note: I can't handle the even by MouseMove from the parent because i will have alot of instances from this user control as each user control works as a row inside a table.

Comment: Maybe share (a part of) your implementation with us, that way we can better see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to check whether the mouse pointer is over our control or not in each event handler.

The following helper method will tell us if the mouse pointer is over a control (whether it be a UserControl or a standard Control)

```
private bool IsMouseOver(Control control)
{
    return control.ClientRectangle.Contains(control.PointToClient(MousePosition));
}
```

By testing the return value of this method, we can determine in the MouseLeave event that the mouse is still over our user control, and manipulate the button's visibility accordingly:

```
private void UserControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsMouseOver(this))
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void UserControl1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsMouseOver(this))
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That Worked, Many Thanks!